# Should I use interfaces types for the function along with the parameter and return types?

Tags: typescript

This is a function that can be used as the Geolocation API position callback:

```
const showPosition: PositionCallback = (position: Position): void => console.log(position);
```

With that `PositionCallback`, I'd like to know whether should I remove the parameter and return type, or not.

Comment: Yes: they're redundant. Or no, if you find the code more readable this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are redundant because the [definition of PositionCallback](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#position-callback) specifies the types, so TypeScript is guaranteed to infer them for the right-hand side of the assignment.

Comment: Would you still use the return and parameters types, even though you know it is redundant, just to improve readability?

Comment: I don't have a general rule for every case, but yes, I do sometimes keep the types for readability even if they're not required for type checking.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of style. The types are inferred so the compiler will be happy either way.

The advantage of keeping the PositionCallback type explicit is if the type changes in the future, you compiler will raise errors at all the points where you need to correct the type. Without it you won't get an error until you pass showPosition to something that expects a PositionCallback so it can take a bit longer to fix the code.

Comment: Would you still use the return and parameters types, even though you know it is redundant, just to improve readability?

Comment: So, would be better to remove the types for return and parameters, but not otherwise?

Comment: @JoãoLucas I would definitely keep the PositionCallback type explicit so I get early compilations errors if something changes. I'd be less likely to keep the explicit types to the right of the equals as my IDE can show me the type if I really need it. However if was an API not being used much the app then I might make them explicit to help people along.